# Pass Inherited Class Constructor Arguments to Base Constructor Arguments

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

What is the "C# way" to pass arguments of inherited class constructors *to* base class constructors? Would this require that I override the base_model string in the base class?

```
// Base class
class vehicle
{
    private string base_model = String.Empty;

    vehicle(string model)
    {
        this.base_model = model;
    }

}


// Inherited classes
class tesla : vehicle
{
    private readonly string model = "Model S";      // This is unchanging

    tesla(string model) : base ( **pass model to base_model** )
    {
        // Initialize
    }
}

class ferrari : vehicle
{
    private readonly string model = "458 Spider";      // This is unchanging

    ferrari(string model) : base ( **pass model to base_model** )
    {
        // Initialize
    }

}
```

### Edit

@JohnLBevan brought another question to my attention:

This brings to mind another question: is it possible to have no constructor arguments for the `tesla` class (or the `ferrari` class for that matter) and automatically pass the `model` variable (i.e. `"Model S"`) to the `base_model`?

Comment: IMO the actual model instance name doesn't belong to base. It belongs to the instance.

Comment: @MitchWheat could you provide some code as an example? Not sure how to apply that.

Comment: I second the [comment from Mitch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708941/pass-inherited-class-constructor-arguments-to-base-constructor-arguments#comment38320661_24708941) - what you are doing is bad - the base class is not supposed to know anything about the extending (derived) class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A far more OO standards compliant way to do this is to use an abstract property. This means the base class has *defined* the property but the extending classes must *implement* it. This also means you cannot directly create an instance of `vehicle`, instead you must create one of the derived types.

```
abstract class vehicle
{

    vehicle() {   }

    public abstract string Model { get; }

}


// Inherited classes
class tesla : vehicle
{
    private readonly string model = "Model S";      // This is unchanging

    public override string Model { get { return model; }}
}

class ferrari : vehicle
{

    public override string Model { get { return "458 Spider"; }}

}
```

The only time you really want to be passing values from derived constructors to base constructors is when those values are actively used in the base class. This is a normally when you've overridden a base constructor, or you are using a dependency injection or dependency resolution pattern. The base class should not act as an aggregation of information from the derived class.

Comment: Fantastic, this is the "C# way" I was looking for, especially in regards to OOP. I also appreciate your explanation of when derived constructors to base constructors is applicable.

Answer (score 4):

Exactly what you've done, only putting the variable name in where you had the asterisks:

```
// Inherited classes    
class tesla : vehicle
{
    private readonly string model = "Model S";      // This is unchanging

    tesla(string model) : base ( model )
    {
        // Initialize
    }
}
```

You also need to ensure that the base class's constructor is visible to its subclasses (i.e. is not private)

```
// Base class
class vehicle
{
    private string base_model = String.Empty;

    protected vehicle(string model)
    {
        this.base_model = model;
    }
}
```

Comment: This brings to mind another question: is it possible to have no constructor arguments for the `tesla` class (or the `ferrari` class for that matter) and automatically pass the `model` variable (i.e. `"Model S"`) to the `base_model`?

Comment: Yes; to distinguish the constructor's parameter from the private readonly field you pass `model` for the former and `this.model` for the latter.